# Java: compilation error with generic function reference

Tags: java, generics, lambda, java-8, method-reference

Could someone help me to fix this compilation error, please?

I 'd like to define a map  method in the generic interface called Suite and use it like this:

```
Suite < Integer > suite2 = Suite.from("34", "78", "23").map(Integer::parseInt);

assertEquals(3, suite.size());
assertEquals(34, (int)suite.get(0));
assertEquals(78, (int)suite.get(1));
assertEquals(23, (int)suite.get(2));
```

The the call to the same method with a function and parameter compile well:

```
Suite<Integer> suite1 = Suite.from(1, 2).map(x -> x * 2);

assertEquals(2, suite.size());
assertEquals(2, (int)suite.get(0));
assertEquals(4, (int)suite.get(1));
```

So I've defined the method in the interface like this

```
public interface Suite<E> {

    public <E> Suite<E> map(int i, Function<? super E, ? extends E> f);
}
```

Note: this is almost the same protytype as the map method of Stream class
 (except the paramter i )

My problem is in my test, this line does not compile:

```
map(Integer::parseInt)
```

because of these errors:

> - The type Integer does not define `toString(Object)` that is applicable here.
> - Type mismatch: cannot convert `Suite<Object>` to `Suite<String>`

I'm tried to redefine the function with a `Supplier<E>` but it does not work.

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense.  What kind of parameter do you expect to pass to the function? `E` or not `E`?

Comment: just spitballing here, what if you used `.span(1, x -> x.toString())`

Comment: THis might be your problem.  Function<? super E, ? extends E>

Comment: try to define 2 generic classes

`public <E, F> Suite<F> map(int i, Function<? super E, ? extends F>  ;`

Comment: Please see my updated post with all the use case test.

Comment: Radistao, your proposition does not work. This line does not compile anymore   : Suite<Integer> suite = Suite.from(1, 2).map(x -> x * 2) whereas it compiled with my version. Thanks anyway !

Comment: corsiKa, it works if I change the call like you have proposed. But I cannot change it which is the specification how the class Suite could be used.

Comment: well, it is completely mess now:  `Suite<E> map(int i, Function<? super E, ? extends E> f)` accepts 2 arguments (Integer and Function, but `map(Integer::parseInt)` passes only Function, missing Integer. Isn't it?

Comment: Radisto, you are right. Thank you! There is no problem with the map method. This non-static map compiles well. My problem was the static function span. I 'll try to see why static method makes  the program test not compiled.

Comment: Finally, it seems that the problem is due to the test which is not compatible with new java version : calling Integer::toString is not valid anymore and now, it is recommanded to  use Objects::toString .... Thank you all for your help !

Comment: You have two unrelated type parameters with the same name `<E>` in your interface. That’s *not*, how `Stream.map` works…

Answer (score 2):

```
 Function<? super E, ? extends E> function
```

Integer is not a super class of String, hence this fails:

```
Suite <String> suite1 = Suite.span(1, Integer::toString);
```

reference:  [Difference between <? super T> and <? extends T> in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java)

Comment: In fact, this method must be able used in the same way the map of the Stream class. (Please my post updated). And I used the same prototype. The test case is the specification so I think it must work

Comment: @Toto Your is not at all the same. `Stream.map()` has two generic types: `T` (the input type, defined at the class level) and `R` (the return type).

Answer (score 2):

Usually functional mapping expects type changing, e.g. argument and result types are diverged:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-

> Suite < Integer > suite2 = Suite.from("34", "78", "23").map(Integer::parseInt);

Here you change `String` type to `Integer`, thus you can't use common `E` generic name like

```
public <E> Suite<E> map(int i, Function<? super E, ? extends E> f);
```

but:

```
public <T, R> Suite<R> map(int i, Function<? super T, ? extends R> f);
```

or:

```
public interface Suite<E> {
    public <R> Suite<R> map(int i, Function<? super E, ? extends R> f);
}
```

Comment: radistao, juste tried your idea . So I added the second type R : public <R> Suite<R> map(int i, Function<? super E, ? extends R> f);  but many lines won't  compile. Example:   Suite.from("abc", "def", "ghi")
      .map(String::length)

Comment: Radistao, other error: this line does not compile any more, after adding a return type R in the prototype :  Suite<Integer> suite = Suite.from(1, 2).map(x -> x * 2);

Comment: could you show whole `Suite` class? It is not clear what exactly should be done

Comment: as i mentioned in another commend above: you methods arguments list are mismatched

Comment: public interface Suite<E> {

 @SafeVarargs
 public static <E> Suite<E> from(E... values) {
  return new SuiteImpls<>(values);
 }
 
 public <R> Suite<R> map(int i, Function<? super E, ? extends R> fun); }

Comment: The interface is almost empty. I'am trying to get an interface working with the test program.

Comment: remove `int i, ` from map function